# Are macros guaranteed no over head?

Tags: c++, c

As a programmer I've been taught to prefer the keyword **inline** to macro definitions for small functions. I know that inline is known to be more safe due to macro definitions doing no type checking, however I am told that inline is only a request for the compiler to actually replace the code, and the compiler doesn't have to accept that request, so I am wondering are macros requests as well or are they guaranteed to have no over head time?

Comment: Making the code longer is also overhead of a sort.

Comment: The compiler is required to generate the same code as if all macros are expanded in the first place, according to the C++ specification.

Comment: Macros are guaranteed to be expanded inline during the compilation by the preprocessor. However, this doesn't mean "no overhead". *Larger* code may be *slower* code. That's why the compiler decided to ignore your request to inline. You do not need to worry about this. Let the compiler handle it.

Comment: This is for C or C++?

Comment: You are told lore from one or two decades ago -- compilers don't care about `inline`.

Comment: The `inline` keyword is foremost a linker directive. The compiler doesn't trust you any more, than it could throw a piano on this one.

Comment: Thank you for your comments, but Quentin you say that they don't care about inline any more, do you mean it just accepts the request?

Comment: No. The compiler ignores your request, and performs its own inline optimization evaluations. The linker, on the other hand, will always respect the [`inline` specifier](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/inline).

Comment: Well thank you all for your comments, it is much appreciated.

Comment: There is a situation where using a macro incurs overhead vs. using a function.  Consider this macro: `#define MAX(a, b) ((a) > (b) ? (a) : (b))` which is used in this code: `max_result = MAX(SlowFunction(), 0);` `SlowFunction` will be evaluated first for the comparison, and if the comparison is true, it will be evaluated a second time to get the result.  Whats worse, if `SlowFunction` has side-effects or might return a different value on the second evaluation, this could end up being a hard-to-find bug.  But, if `MAX` is defined as a function accepting 2 values, these problems can't happen.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Macros are textual replacements performed before the compilation step - they cannot have "run-time overhead" in the way a function call could. Still, this is not a good reason to use macros instead of functions, as compilers will automatically inline functions even without the `inline` keyword with optimizations enabled. Furthermore, using link time optimization `-flto` will allow inlining between TUs.

Answer (score 2):

Macros are compile-time things. They never appear as macros in the compiled code. If you define something like

```
#define MyVar 5
```

And you do in the code:

```
double y = MyVar*MyVar;
```

This is exactly like:

```
double y = 5*5;
```

At compile time, the `MyVar` macro is *replaced* by the value you defined. There's absolutely no overhead at run-time.

Comment: s/compile-time/preprocessor.

Comment: @Barry: The preprocessor is part of the compiler.

Comment: @KeithThompson Part of the same binary yes, but the preprocessing step happens before the actual compilation step.

Comment: @Barry: It may or may not be part of the same binary, depending on the implementation (for example, gcc uses a separate preprocessor). But the language doesn't make such a distinction. [N1570](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/n1570.pdf) 5.1.1.2 defines 8 translation phases; the preprocessor corresponds to the first 5 or so.

Answer (score 1):

Macros are a preprocessor feature.

The preprocessor modifiers your program in a purely textual way, and you can actually see the results of it if you run the preprocessor separately.

With gcc you can do that with either `gcc -E` or `cpp`.
I do this quite often when I debug my macros.

Example main.c:

```
#include <stdio.h>

#define MC_repeat(X)  \
    for(int _i=0;_i<(X);_i++)

#define rt return

#define MC_xputs(X) if(0>puts(X)) rt -1;


int main()
{
    MC_repeat(5) 
        MC_xputs("hello world");
    rt 0;
}
```

Output of `gcc -E main.c | tail`:

```
# 2 "main.c" 2
# 11 "main.c"

# 11 "main.c"
int main()
{
    for(int _i=0;_i<(5);_i++)
        if(0>puts("hello world")) return -1;;
    return 0;
}
```

When you compile such a source, it is effectively as if you ran the preprocesser first and then piped the results to the compiler proper.

gcc doesn't actually do it this way (so you get better error messages), but you can force it to:

```
#actually pipes preprocessor output to the compiler proper
gcc -E main.c | gcc -x cpp-output
```

Comment: *"purely textual"* is inaccurate. The preprocessor does perform some parsing. If you exchange `MC_repeat(5)` with `(MC_repeat)(5)`, the preprocessor will no longer replace the `MC_repeat` symbol.